# Why does Fetch Python Plugins responded with only the installed ones?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, python-addin

I use QGIS 1.8. Whenever I demand to install plugins through Fetch Python Plugins it displays only those the already installed. I couldn't find for example; point sampling, group stats and photo2shape plugins. Can one help me?

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Which OS you are using?

Answer (score 1):

In the Fetch Python plugins dialogue. have a look at the repository tab.

There should be at least the official Repo http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml

with status `connected`.

If the Repo is missing, add it, if it is not connected, internet access is unavailable.

If QGIS has no internet access, you can always download the plugins manually from the URL, and unzip them into C:\user\< username >.qgis\python\plugins or the Linux equivalent

Comment: Not having the proxy set up properly will also fail silently.